# The method used for computation of factor scores in lavaan from confirmatory factor analysis

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I'm running CFA {lavaan}; function cfa() in R.

This article
https://psychology.okstate.edu/faculty/jgrice/personalitylab/Grice_FactorScores_PM_2001.pdf 
details a number of different methods for extracting factor scores from factor analysis, based on a linear combination of values from each variable.

I'm wondering if anyone knows which of these methods is used when running the predict() function on a model defined by the cfa() function in {lavaan} in R?

For exploratory factor analysis, using the fa() function in the {psych} package, you can choose which factor extraction method to use. I can't see an option to choose which method to use for cfa() in {lavaan}, nor can I find an explanation of which method is used.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: If you are only asking how the R code works, that would be off topic here (see our [help/on-topic]). You could ask on the r-help listserv, I suppose. If you have a statistical question about CFA, please edit to clarify. Otherwise, this will end up being closed.

Comment: searching the site for `factor scores lavaan` returnes more than 3 questions very similar to yours. Did you see them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lavaan` objects are an S4 class, so to view the predict method, you would type `getMethod('predict', 'lavaan')`. Basically, the workhorse function is `lavPredict` which you should consult the help on.

Basically, the default method returns the predicted latent variable value which is estimated in the M step of the EM maximum likelihood estimation of the latent model.